# #region guidelines for inherited interfaces?

Tags: c#

Consider these interfaces:

```
interface IBar
{
    void bar();
}

interface IFoo : IBar
{
    void foo();
}
```

It is common to group code using `#region` blocks. In a concrete class implementing `IFoo`, I can think of two region configurations that make sense.

**My question is; which one is the preferred convention?** Please motivate your answer.

### A:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    #region IFoo interface
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
    #endregion
}
```

### B:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    #region IFoo interface
    void foo() {}
    #endregion

    #region IBar interface
    void bar() {}
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: if your code is short enough, regions are kind of useless. If it's long, maybe it needs some refactoring instead of regions.

Comment: I personally would even avoid regions at all. Have been using them for some time and they did not give any value but made the code harder to read. When having big interfaces - might be good to implement partial classes; small interfaces - don't bother with regions at all.

Comment: Abolish regions! They are the spawn of satan. I cry every time that I see them. It's like "Ooohh, look at this mess. Let's hide it under the carpet". You have done something wrong if you have enough code to motivate regions. You should divide your class into smaller units instead of start using regions.

Comment: If code is bigger than my screen, I like to have it in regions, so that I can put it away tidily when I am not looking at it.  Regions are a huge help when trying to look at 2 functions simultaneously, that are separated by other code.  Endless tiny classes is not the answer, they can also be too small sometimes, and make it hard to compare code.

Comment: Large functions are usually complex to debug and understand as the Cyclomatic complexity always increases. If you instead break down that function into a new class with several methods the Cyclomatic complexity is reduced and the class is therefore much more readable. And a side effect of that is that you start using the composite pattern in the orgininal class which also makes it easier to understand the code.

Comment: I have seen classs, each one together with its own interface, defined for just *one* single function. Please. Stick related ones together in a sensible class, separated by regions. This could turn into a flame war, so that's my last word on the subject. I (heart) regions. :-)

Comment: Who's talking about long functions?  Not me.

Comment: (I rewrote my last comment before I saw your answer). Everything can be abused. Both classes and methods. Neither is good. Cyclomatic complexity is a good meassurement to decide wether a refactoring is nesessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If regions divide up different areas of logic then B is preferred (and is my personal preference).

Comment: And maybe even IBar region inside IFoo region

Answer (score 1):

Ask all the developers in your team to vote on the most readable style, then stick to it.